# Deploy Rails Application with Apache + Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I want to deploy two rails applications on Ubuntu 12.04 - (It's Digital Ocean Server). 
Is it possible to deploy two rails application on Apache + Passenger with only one IP Address means that I have one Digital Ocean and I want deploy two rails application on same server. Is it possible ?

If possible then how ?

Thanks In Advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deploy multiple rails app on a single IP (Apache + Passenger)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922454/how-to-deploy-multiple-rails-app-on-a-single-ip-apache-passenger)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible. You can serve a multitude of Rails apps on a given server. Having one IP address is not an obstacle as the majority of sites are served this way.

For each app you want to create a virtual host record under the directory /etc/apache2/sites-available

Once your virtual host is set up, you want to run this command:

```
sudo a2ensite virtualhostname
```

This will generate a symbolic link in the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled directory.

The detailed, Passenger documentation can be found at http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html and this section should be most helpful to your particular case: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_rack_based_ruby_application_including_rails_gt_3

Comment: As a side note: Recent versions of Passenger even allow different virtual hosts each running different versions of Ruby since the `passenger_ruby` directive can now be set inside the virtual host definition.