# is it possible to have multiple project of rails on same port?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, port

I want to add a new project beside of my current rails app without starting a new server for that.

I think it is impossible to have two rails app on one port but my boss want it.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: format and typo

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible if you configure a web server (nginx, etc) as a reverse proxy to listen on the port you want, and have it forward traffic to the correct app based on subdomain.

Comment: but still i need to run the new app in new port and add it to enginix setup, ok?

Comment: @AliMusavi It could be a local port, or it could be a Unix socket (more efficient) - all depends on how you configure it and whether or not the app is running on the same server as the reverse proxy instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. You can't run two web servers, e.g. Puma, on the same port. That won't work. But you can run one web server to serve two Rails apps. Incoming requests are routed based on either their subdomain (`app1.example.com`) or their path (`example.com/app1`).

A common setup is to use Apache/nginx as the web server in combination with Passenger as the application server. This question ask a similar question and points to Passenger's documentation on how to serve apps from subdomains: [How to deploy multiple rails app on a single IP (Apache + Passenger)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922454/how-to-deploy-multiple-rails-app-on-a-single-ip-apache-passenger)

The configuration depends heavily on your setup, so I can't give you a more detailed answer. But searching for "multiple apps" and the combination of your web and application server should yield enough results and tutorials for you to solve your problem.